# trying to retrieve file from blobstore and send it as mail attachment using google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am trying to design an application that would require me to retrieve data stored in blobstore and send it as attachment. Does google app engine allow this?  From the documentation, i could not find a way to retrieve data from blobstore for processing within the app.. can someone please tell me how to accomplish this? Code examples and/or pointers to related online resources would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now read data from the blobstore, using [BlobReader](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobreaderclass.html), which provides a simple, file-like interface.

Comment: this is for Python. What about Java?

Answer (score 2):

As of now, it seems this isn't possible. You can only cause the the file to be [sent to the client](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html#Serving_a_Blob).

It's possible you could do what you need using a [Datastore Blob](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#BlobProperty)?

It's worth also noting that the Blobstore is "experimental" and may change. It's possible additional functionality may be added that would allow what you'r trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished in two steps using the code from the Complete Sample App.
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview.html#Complete_Sample_App

1) Write a servlet that takes a blobkey and returns the contents of the blob.

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
    throws IOException {
        BlobKey blobKey = new BlobKey(req.getParameter("blob-key"));
        blobstoreService.serve(blobKey, res);
    }
```

2) Within your application, use the URLFetchService.fetch(java.net.URL url) with the proper blobkey to retrieve the blob (as a stream) and attach it to the email.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BlobstoreInputStream](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/blobstore/BlobstoreInputStream) to do almost the same thing as [BlobReader](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobreaderclass.html) do.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/blobstore/BlobstoreInputStream

> BlobstoreInputStream provides an InputStream view of a blob in Blobstore. It is thread compatible but not thread safe: there is no static state, but any multithreaded use must be externally synchronized.